# InsertAfter Not Working

Tags: wordpress, insertafter

I'm trying to add an arrow button on each image on this Wordpress page;

http://storyville.jonmarkoff.com/storyvillewp/our-work/

by using this code;

```
$( "#arrow" ).insertAfter( $( ".youtube_gallery_player a" ) );
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same id. Are you sure you are using the right function? (`insertAfter` has the target to the right, `after` to the left) http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u mean

```
$('<div id="arrow"> </div>').insert...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css from a # (which is an ID and unique) to a class (.arrow).  Usage would be something like:

```
$( ".arrow" ).insertAfter( $( ".youtube_gallery_item" ) );
```